# How can I set the log_stream_prefix to get the cloudwatch data from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get the log from the cloudwatch

my source code is like this below

I can find the group_name in cloudwatch console `/aws/lambda/mylambda`

```
logGroupName = "/aws/lambda/mylambda"

response = logs.describe_log_streams(
        logGroupName=group_name,
        logStreamNamePrefix=log_stream_name_prefix,
        orderBy='LogStreamName',
        descending=True,
    )
```

however, example my `log_stream_name` is changed like this below.

```
2023/05/01/[$LATEST]e6a2f85f7eb74aa9bde07837fc971df7
2023/04/30/[$LATEST]39b7ffa511434a65ba4bb4bd915485fd
2023/04/29/[$LATEST]3c2c75965ef2422f86b1624ef042d54b
```

What should I set for log_stream_name_prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is asking for the prefix (the first part of the name) not the full name. So for example to query all log streams for the day of `2023/04/29` the log stream prefix would be: `2023/04/29/[$LATEST]`